# Быстрая реализация FIFO на Haskell'e?

Tags: очередь, haskell, fifo

Стандартный список (`[a]`) позволяет быстро вставить в конец и быстро вынуть из конца списка.

Допустим, можно создать "спископодобный" тип  и функцию `push` для него, которая держит первый добавленный элемент в "быстрой" доступности, так, что можно эффективно листать эту очередь от более старых к более новым:

```
data Queue a = Empty | Element a (Queue a)

push :: a -> Queue a -> Queue a
push a Empty             = Element a Empty
push a (Value b pointer) = Element b (push a pointer)
```

Но тут существенный недостаток - при добавлении нового элемента он рекурсивно уходит "вглубь" очереди, то есть с ростом очереди новое добавление будет все медленнее и медленнее.

По сути, в этом вопрос - как на языке Haskell реализовать контейнер `FIFO`, так, чтобы быстро добавлять новый элемент **и** быстро считывать из него, начиная с более старых элементов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очередь можно организовать с помощью [двух стеков](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D0.B4.D0.B2.D1.83.D1.85_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.85), в качестве которых использовать те же списки. Время добавления в очередь будет константным, время извлечения - амортизированно константным. Т.е. отдельные операции извлечения могут занимать много времени, но усредненное время для всех операций будет константным.

Также для этих целей можно использовать контейнер [`Seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.1.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html). Он предоставляет эффективный доступ как к началу, так и к концу последовательности, и реализован с помощью [деревьев](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree).

Не могу не отметить, что ваш тип `Queue` полностью повторяет структуру встроенного типа `[]`. В целях обучения использовать такие типы допустимо, но на практике гораздо эффективнее будет использовать именно встроенный список, опционально обернув его в `newtype`, если потребуется.

```hs
newtype Queue a = Queue [a]
```

Хотя, само собой, для эффективной реализации очереди ни встроенный список, ни ваш `Queue` не подходят.